# Eclipse won't resolve new Gradle dependencies

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, gradle

I'm new to `Gradle` and have the `Gradle Eclipse plugin` (running `Spring Tool Suite`). Whenever I add a new dependency in the `Gradle` build file, like this for example:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final'
    ...
}
```

`Eclipse` can't resolve the imports in the classes that need these. What am I missing here?

Is there some "update project" command I need to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see... I needed to right-click the build.gradle file -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies.